# Fullcalendar - slow button click response

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

I'm using Fullcalendar v2.4.0 and related plugin Scheduler v1.0.2 with all required dependencies. jQuery-ui is at v1.11.4.

I'm loading resources via Ajax call using Fullcalendar built-in method of:

```
resources: {
     url: 'resources_feed.php',
     type: 'POST'
}
```

resources_feed.php simply returns few lines of dummy data.

And for the events, using a similar built-in method of:

```
events: {
     url: 'events_feed.php',
     type: 'POST' 
}
```

events_feed.php returning few lines of dummy data.

It all works as expected until I plug in more realistic large amount of data as resources but still keeping the events data same.

The problem I experience is that button clicks like views (Day, Week, Month), Today and left/right arrows are responding after a delay of min 2 seconds sometimes longer. It behaves as if there's a delay set for a few seconds between button click and event firing. I tried to put an alert in the onClick event and alert is displayed after this few second delay.

I tested another button outside Fullcalendar object but on the same page and that works as expected, ie firing as soon as you click the button. This rules out page or jQuery issues. Same behaviour in Firefox and Chrome.

If I switch resource loading back to dummy data then buttons start firing as soon as clicked.

I can't figure out why a large amount of data still to be fetched can affect button response even before triggering an Ajax call.

Anyone seen this before? Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is on your events_feed.php maybe you are loading all the data on every call. Maybe you are not catching properly the Start and End parameters on every button.

The feed.php should catch the start and the end on every call. Something like this:

```
$start = $_GET['start']);
$end = $_GET['end']);

// then select database
```

I had this problem when i started to use fullcalendar.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks David, using Firebug I can see that the delay is before ajax call is initiated. As mentioned, I placed an alert in the onClick event of the button and alert is displayed after this delay as opposed to instantly. A delay after an ajax call starts is understandable but why before..?